# Where are the application events in the latest ASP.NET MVC 5 version?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to implement the requirement where the application counts the number of visitors to the site.

So, therefore I need to know the events like application start event which I believe is the way to count the number of user visits to my site.

I created a project in .NET 8 and ASP.NET MVC 5, but could not find any application start event in the solution explorer. Earlier there was a configure method somewhere in the app to configure the app to the desired need. But couldn't find such configure method in the solution explorer now.

Can someone please help me regarding this to know how to configure the app to implement this task of counting number of visits to the site.

I want to familiarize my self with this application event start event in the this new version of ASP.NET MVC.

Thanks.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC 5 was based on the old / classic / full **.NET** framework (up to v4.8.1) - however, **.NET 8** is the latest version of the **.NET Core** family - and ASP.NET Core MVC is its web stack. This is very similar - but **not** identical - to ASP.NET MVC 5 ....

Comment: Plus, events like "Application Start" were used in ASP.NET **Webforms** - which has long been superseeded by ASP.NET MVC and now ASP.NET **Core** MVC .....